# How can I prove that the high-degree independent set problem is NP-hard?

Tags: np-complete, np

I'm learning about NP Completeness, and I have come across the following problem

The decision-version of the high-degree independent set (henceforth "HDIS") problem is stated as follows: Given a graph $G = (V, E)$ with $n$ vertices, does $G$ have an independent set of size $k$, consisting of vertices with degree at least $n/2$? Prove that HDIS is NP-complete.

I'm provided with a hint that I'm supposed to perform a reduction from independent set.

I was wondering if someone can please check my work.

---

First, HDIS is in NP because given a certificate (just a list of vertices), we can compute the degree of each vertex, and verify that no two vertices are adjacent and the degree of each vertex is at least $n/2$ is polynomial time.

Now we need to show that HDIS is as hard as any other NP-complete problem.

I was thinking about starting with an instance of independent set (so a graph $G = (V, E)$) and subsequently constructing a new graph $G'$ with every vertex whose degree was less than $n/2$ in the original graph removed. From here, I think that I can just call my oracle to HDIS and return "yes" if and only if my oracle returns "yes".

---

This is one of the first problems that I am solving, and I am wondering if someone can please tell me if this is correct?

Comment: We discourage "please check my answer", as the only possible answer is "yes" or "no", which is unlikely to be useful to others in the future.  Better to ask a classmate or your instructors to grade your work.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that. I should have read the rules before posting. Should I remove my question?

Comment: Suppose I have a 5-vertex path graph, and want to know if this graph contains an independent set of size 3. What is the correct answer? And what would your proposed reduction algorithm say the answer should be?